# ORDER BY 2 Columns in alphabetical order, mix both columns rather than separate sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, mysqli

I have 2 types of records, ones that start with the Owners name, and others that start with the companies name.

I need to output all of these records in alphabetical order. For example like this.

```
Apple (company)
Bradley (name)
Tim (name)
Xerox (company)
```

Currently all the records sort separately, so first the company names sort, and then the names, which results in this.

```
Apple (company)
Xerox (company)
Bradley (name)
Tim (name)
```

This is the current query I have:

```
$all = "SELECT * FROM refs ORDER BY a_s_name ASC, company_a ASC";
```

So to confirm I need the records mixed sorted so they are in alphabetical regardless if it is a company or a name.

Thank you for any help

Comment: What is stored in your table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Stored in the table is references for quotes in books and websites... Some have a author and others have a Company, so they need to be sorted in alphabetical order so I can output an entire list sorted

Comment: Do any have both author and company? `"SELECT * FROM refs ORDER BY COALESCE(a_s_name, company_a) ASC"`

Comment: Post some sample data.

Comment: From the Database ? I will upload a picture with dummy data

Comment: We don't need your real data. Just post four fake rows in table form, so we can see how your table looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not clear from your question, but I assume your table actually looks like this:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----+
| a_s_name | company_a | other_column | another_one | ... |
+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----+
| NULL     | Apple     | foo          | bar         | ... |
| Bradley  | NULL      | foo          | bar         | ... |
| Tim      | NULL      | foo          | bar         | ... |
| NULL     | Xerox     | foo          | bar         | ... |
+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----+
```

If that is correct, I'd order by an `IFNULL()` condition:

```
SELECT * FROM refs ORDER BY IFNULL(a_s_name, company_a) ASC
```

That way, if the `a_s_name` column contains a `NULL` value, the value of `company_a` is used for sorting.

If your columns do not contain `NULL` values but empty strings, you could use a generic `IF()` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM refs ORDER BY IF(a_s_name = '', company_a, a_s_name) ASC
```

**Edit**: For `NULL`-values, the `COALESCE()` option suggested by Mark Baker might actually be faster:

```
SELECT * FROM refs ORDER BY COALESCE(a_s_name, company_a) ASC
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer and fantastic help. Thankyou very much, I will accept as correct as soon as the 5 min timer is up :) Thanks again

Comment: This is the query which works perfectly:  $all = "SELECT * FROM refs ORDER BY IF(a_s_name = '', company_a, a_s_name) ASC"; 
 thank you :)

Comment: Can someone let me know what I did wrong in my initial question to deserve a down vote, so I can improve my questions next time ?